# Loggin in to Github with Python, Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub

Tags: python, cookies

I am trying to login to Python, I know they have an API, but this is more to build my learning skills with Python, I may eventually go the API way, but anyway, I am trying to login to github, and with my script I am getting the error/response:

```
Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub.
```

Which means I must enable cookies,right? But I am sure I have.. Here is my code

```
def github_login():

    # get the auth token, and sign in button value to sen with the params
    git = bs(requests.get('https://github.com/login').text, 'html.parser')
    auth_token = git.find("input", {"name": "authenticity_token"}).attrs['value']
    commit = git.find("input", {"name": "commit"}).attrs['value']   

    #Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub
    session = requests.session()


    #send the data, with auth tokenn and button value
    data = {
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'commit' : commit,
        'authenticity_token' : auth_token
    }

    headers = {
        "Host": "www.github.com",
        "Origin": "https://www.github.com",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5",
    }

    login = session.post('https://github.com/session', data=data)

    print login.text
    if login.status_code == 301:
        logged_in = True
        return True

    return False
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same cookie must persist across requests, so ensure your GET and POST requests are both made within the same session:

```
def github_login():
    s = requests.Session()

    # get the auth token, and sign in button value to sen with the params
    soup = bs(s.get('https://github.com/login').text, 'html.parser')
```

Aaaand:

```
    login = s.post('https://github.com/session', data=data)
```