# How does GitHub know if I am logged in?

Tags: javascript, session, authentication, github, local-storage

I deleted the `localStorage` but that didn't help. Does GitHub maintain a database of IP address of the users who are logged in? Or the browser headers?

Comment: Did you delete your cookies too?

Comment: They store it in a Cookies. If you clear the Cookies, you should be logged out.

Answer (score 0):

Even before deleting any GitHub cookie ([which you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42430800/6309)), you can quickly test that with [opening a private/incognito session](https://www.howtogeek.com/269265/how-to-enable-private-browsing-on-any-web-browser/).
In that new session, you should see you are no longer logged in to GitHub (or any other service for that matter)